# Enable Passwordless Authentication with ssh

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, public-key-encryption

How can I enable password less authentication with SSH.

This is what I have when I was looking for /.ssh folder.

```
bash-3.00$ cd ~/.ssh
bash-3.00$ pwd
/home/uname/.ssh
bash-3.00$ ls -lt
total 2
-rw-r--r--   1 uname   gid-uname     489 Jul 26 18:55 known_hosts
```

And I don't know what next I have to do here? I need to change the permission of `known_hosts` folder? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your public key to a file called `authorized_keys`.

Make sure that no `group` and `other` permissions are not set.

Comment: This is not a question for  stackoverflow though...

Answer (score 3):

To enable passwordless ssh between remote and local machine, you have to perform these steps on your local machine :-

1st Step> root@localmachine:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa

Note - Considering that .ssh dir is already present in remote machine if not, then do this (ssh root@remotemachine mkdir -p .ssh)

2nd Step> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@remotemachine 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'

3rd Step> root@localmachine:~> ssh root@remotemachine

Answer (score 0):

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

- Generate your keys using `ssh-keygen`
- Copy over your SSH identity to the host (to which you need passwordless login) using `ssh-copy-id`.

`man ssh-keygen` and `man ssh-copy-id` on your system for help.