# SCP Through python is not transferring file

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi, scp

I have two Raspberry Pi's. I am trying to transfer files from one Pi to the other using scp. I am trying to do this through Python because the program that will be transferring files is a python file.

below is the shell script I have for the SCP part (Blurred out the pass and IP):

```
#!/bin/sh
sshpass -p ######## scp test.txt pi@IP:/home/pi
```

and below is the Python Script that launches that Shell script.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./ssh.sh'])
print("DONE")
```

For some reason the python script doesnt kick back any errors and hits the print line but the file is not transferred. When i run the scp command outside of python the file transfers just fine. Am I doing something incorrect here?

****EDIT****
I cant even get Subprocess to work with this which is why i ended up using na shell script. Here is my attempt with Subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sshpass -p ######## scp test.txt pi@IP:/home/pi")
print"DONE"
```

Again I get no errors, but the file is not transferred

****EDIT #2****
So I found out that because sshpass is being used, scp isnt prompting me to add the IP to known hosts, as a result the file simply isnt trnasferred at all. I need a way to add this acceptance into the script IE I ge the following if I launch the command without sshpass:

`The authenticity of host 'IP (IP)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 13:91:24:8e:6f:21:98:1f:5b:3a:c8:42:7a:88:e9:91.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`

I want to communicate to pass "yes\n" to this prompt as well as the password afterwards. Is this possible?

Comment: Capture the return value like this `res = subprocess.call("...")` and see what it says there. Or use `check_call`, which raises exceptions to see what happened.

Comment: @ipinak I've updated the question with my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much easier way of tackling all of this

```
sshpass -p ###### scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no test.txt  pi@IP:/home/pi
```

The -o switch allows me to auto store the IP into known hosts thus I do not need to communicate with the shell at all. The interaction from Python to Shell works with that addition; Doing this solely through subprocess also works.

Answer (score 0):

**For the first query**

You can use 'subprocess.popen' to get output(STDOUT) and error(STDERR) for the executed command.

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'sshpass -p ****** scp dinesh.txt root@256.219.210.135:/root'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print "Output is ",out
print "Error is ",err
```

If you execute above code with wrong password, the you will get below output:

```
[root@centos /]# python code.py
Output is
Error is  Permission denied, please try again.
```

In this case, if the file is successfully transferred, then there is no output. 
If you execute command like 'ls -l' then output will be printed.

**For your second query (****EDIT #2****)**

Options are :

1. Password less SSH. [Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728697/enable-passwordless-authentication-with-ssh)
2. [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to try other approaches it worth to use SCPClient from scp import.