# Why do I get "account expired" for root access over rsh, even though the account works for local login?

Tags: solaris, rsh

I'm using rsh in a script to copy stuff from a Solaris 11 master server to a newly installed one. I know, ssh is safer but I would like to avoid the hassle of passwords, as this all takes place in a closed network anyway.

I have enabled the rsh service (this is by default disabled in Solaris 11). I have listed the connecting client in /etc/hosts.equiv on the server. rsh then works fine for normal user accounts. For root, I first got "access denied". Copying hosts.equiv to /root/.rhosts made that go away. But instead, I get "account expired". Which is not true, it is perfectly possible to login locally to the root account.

Comment: SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: *I would like to avoid the hassle of passwords* [Enable Passwordless Authentication with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728697/enable-passwordless-authentication-with-ssh)